# HERE maps for JavaScript API: How to get all noise points markers and clusters from the map?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I need to find all`.requestMarkers` which returns all cluster and noise point markers which intersect with the provided rectangular area.

Right now I can find all markers and cluster on Visual side of map

```js
let viewBounds = map.getViewBounds(); //view bounds of map
let mapZoom = map.getZoom(); //map zoom
let arrayPoints = clusteredDataProvider.requestMarkers(viewBounds,mapZoom); //marker and cluster that we can see on map
```

But how I can get those markers and cluster from all map?

Comment: Do you mean things outside the viewport?

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your theme within [Provider's options](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.clustering.Provider.html#.Options). All is explained in [Clustering custom theme](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/clustering/custom-cluster-theme) example. The `theme` expects two callbacks, where you should create your map object. There you can for example add it to some global array for later usage:

```js
let objects = [];

let CUSTOM_THEME = {
  getClusterPresentation: function(cluster) {
    let marker = new H.map.Marker(cluster.getPosition());
    objects.push(marker);
    return marker;
  }
  getNoisePresentation: function(noisePoint) {
    let marker = new H.map.Marker(noisePoint.getPosition());
    objects.push(marker);
    return marker;
  }
}

let clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(
  <YOUR_DATA_POINTS>,
  {
    theme: CUSTOM_THEME
  });
```

Here is simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dat64zm/18/) example which counts all clusters and noisePoints.

**Note**: additionally in API version 3.1 you could simply call `clusteredDataProvider.getRootGroup().getObjects()`

Comment: Hi, yes i need just all clustered objects. When I try to use "clusterProvider.getRootGroup().getObjects()" I have an error "clusteredDataProvider.getRootGroup is not a function". getObjects() is also dont work with clusterProvider ((

Comment: Sorry, my bad: in your case it should be `clusteredDataProvider.getRootGroup().getObjects()`. And code works for latest API version: 3.1. You should update your scripts to load latest API (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js)

Comment: In my project used 3.0 version. I cant update it( Is there any way to do this with 3.0 version?

Comment: Updated the answer + added jsfiddle example. Hope it helps.